# How to check for a cookie at the start of every request?

Tags: playframework-2.0

I'd like to check for a cookie in my Global.class onRequest override, but I'm getting an error "There is no HTTP Context available from here".  I know this will likely involve some sort of Action composition, but I'm frankly frustrated with Play's documentation and lack of robust examples.  Here's what I'm trying to accomplish.

1. Check for cookie at start of every request
2. If cookie is set, validate the value and if it's valid set a session variable.  If cookie is not set, continue.
3. Continue with request.

An outline of a recipe that will allow this with some basic code examples would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I do it:

```
@With({EnrichWithUser.class})
public class CouponController extends Controller {
    @With({EnrichWithUser.class})
    public static Result test(){
        return Results.ok("TEST");
    }
}
```

The whole controller or one particular method should be annotated with an action. And within an action you can get access to session. The code above does not represent your scenario, but you'll get the idea:

```
public class EnrichWithUser extends Action.Simple {
    public Result call(Http.Context ctx) throws Throwable {

    User user = (User)ctx.args.get("user");

    if(user == null){
        String email = ctx.session().get("email");
        if(email != null){
            user = User.findByEmail(email);
            ctx.args.put("user", user);
        }
    } else {
        //System.out.println("USER OBTAINED FROM SESSION");
    }

    return delegate.call(ctx);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the simple and to-the-point example.  Still can't get it to work with my onRequest override in Global, but annotating all my controllers works just fine.